# Base64 canonical encodings

Tags: haskell, encoding, base64, decoding

I'm trying to test that `encode` and `decode` functions (defined in `Data.ByteString.Base64.Lazy`) are inverse:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

encoded :: Gen BL.ByteString
encoded = do
  body <- concat <$> listOf (group 0)
  end <- group =<< choose (0, 2)
  return . BL.pack $ body <> end
 where
  group :: Int -> Gen [Word8]
  group pad = do
    letters <- vectorOf (4 - pad)
      . elements . map (fromIntegral . ord)
      $ ['A'..'Z'] <> ['a'..'z'] <> ['0'..'9'] <> ['+','/','=']
    return $ letters <> replicate pad 61  -- 61 is ascii for =

prop_encDec = forAll encoded $ \b ->
  [b] == (encode <$> rights [decode b])
```

But QuickCheck discovers a problem there:

```
=== prop_encDec ===
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):
"1yx="
```

I have investigated that the problem must be related to non-canonical encodings, but I have difficulties understanding what is it and how to deal with it. Can you please explain on this example why decoding “1yx=” and re-encoding produces “1yw=”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `x` does contain ones at positions that are not relevant for the encoding.

Let me elaborate:
The base64 string `1yx=` will be decoded to following binary pattern

```
base64: 1      y      x      =
binary: 000001 110010 110001 000000
```

however the `=` at the end of the string tells the encoder that the last 8 bits are not relevant so

```
000001 110010 110001 000000
^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^
```

only the marked bits will be decoded to

```
binary: 000001 110010 1100
```

as you can see the last two bits (`01`) encoded by the `x` are ignored

Then if we encode the decoded data the encoder will fill up the stream of bits with zero bits, resulting in

```
binary: 000001 110010 110000 000000
                          ^^ ^^^^^^
base64: 1      y      w      =
```

So to conclude: The encoder can't *"correctly"* re-encode the decoded `1yx=` because it contains information that gets lost due to decoding.

For your testing purposes I would suggest to swap the order of operation.
So generate some random string as input, encode it and then decode it and compare it to the original input.

You also might want to checkout the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) section of the Wikipedia article for Base64 encoding. It contains goods examples regarding the padding of data.

---

**On canonical and non-canonical encoding:**

A base64 string is canonical if and only if all padded bits are zero, if one of the padded bits is not zero the string is non-canonical.
So if a base64 string has one `=` at the end, then the last 8 bits must be zero for it to be canonical and if the string has two `=` at the end then the last 16 bits must be zero.

So the string `1yx=` is non-canonical, because as we saw above one of the padded bits is one.
On the other hand the string `1yw=` is canonical because all 8 padded bits are zero.

Comment: Thanks. So what is a canonical encoding after all? According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648.html#section-3.5: "if the input is only one octet for a base 64 encoding, then all six bits of the first symbol are used, but only the first two bits of the next symbol are used. These pad bits MUST be set to zero by conforming encoders. If this property do not hold, there is nocanonical representation of base-encoded data". Do I understand this correctly: canonical encoding is when we lose the last symbol, but don't distort it?

Comment: @kirillfedorov I updated the answer to say a bit about canonical and non-canonical encoding